# RotateTransition current angle javafx2

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

I'm rotating an Image using RotateTransition and if (x,y) is the position of a point on that image initially and the position will keep on changing as the image rotates.
I want to know the poistion of that point at any given time.
how to get that new position of the point?

```
    ImageView wheel= new ImageView();
    wheel.setImage(image);

    rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(10), wheel);
    rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(360);
    rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

//Current method I'm following doesn't seems to be accurate:

```
    rotateTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener(
     new ChangeListener<Duration>() {public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> ov, Duration t, Duration t1) {
            double degree = ((360 * t.toSeconds()) / 10);
            xVal.set(((120) * Math.cos(degree * (Math.PI / 180))) + 162.5);
            yVal.set(((120) * Math.sin(degree * (Math.PI / 180)) + 162.5)); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current angle of the rotation, you should use the [rotateProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#rotateProperty%28%29) of the `ImageView` :

```
    wheel.rotateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, 
                            Number oldValue, 
                            Number newValue) {
            System.err.println("Rotation of " + newValue + " degrees");
        }
    });
```